# why does rails require_tree only works for 1 javascript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have the following manifest:

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
//
//= require_self
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min
//= require default_on_first_input_field
//= require row_shading
//= require long_or_short_details
//= require sortable_hook
//= require date-picker
//= require rails
```

and all the javascript works fine.  So the `row_shading`, the `long_or_short_details` toggle, the `date-picker` and `default_on_first_input_field` all work as expected.

I would like to change to just use require_tree, as in:

```
//= require_tree
//= require_self
```

and when I do this, and restart my server, only my `date-picker` works.
The others - `row_shading`, `default_on_first_field`, `long_or_short_details`, don't work unless I list them individually in the manifest even though they are listed in the header when I try using just `require_tree`:

```
  <script src="/assets/date-picker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/default_on_first_input_field.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/long_or_short_details.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/row_shading.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/sortable_hook.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I thought it might be an ordering issue so I tried

```
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min
//= require default_on_first_input_field
//= require_tree
//= require_self
```

and that does seem a better ordering with `jquery` and `jquery-ui` first, as in:

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/default_on_first_input_field.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/date-picker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/long_or_short_details.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/row_shading.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/sortable_hook.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the javascript for `default_on_first_input_field`, `row_shading and`long_or_short_details` doesn't do not do anything?

date-picker looks like this:

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
$(function(){
var dateInput = $("#datepicker");
var format = 'yy-mm-dd';
dateInput.datepicker({dateFormat: format});
dateInput.datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate(format, dateInput.val()));
});
```

whereas row_shading (for example) looks like:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle-group-row-shading]='toggle'").click(function(){
    $(".row_color_group_1").toggleClass("color_group_1");
    $(".row_color_group_2").toggleClass("color_group_2");
    $(".row_color_group_3").toggleClass("color_group_3");
    $("span#shading_link span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown_shading_link hidden_shading_link");
    $.get('/toggle_row_shading');
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//= require_tree .
```

I think you are missing a `.`

Answer (score 1):

Order of inclusion of JS files is very important when you have dependencies. When you use `require_tree` the order you want would not be there, the files would be included **alphabetically**. i.e. usually you want to have jquery and jquery-ui included first which is what you are doing when including files manually.

If you really want to use require_tree make sure file names are such that all the dependencies are satisfied so if default_on_first_input_field depends on jquery then rename default_on_first_input_field to something like m_default_on_first_input_field to make it work.

But this is really convoluted way to solve this so ideally you should list dependencies manually by requiring all the files individually.